# How to move and display array values from one to another in Assembly Language?

Tags: arrays, assembly, masm, irvine32

I am trying to move the values in `Array1` to `Array2`, and then display them. I have been working on this and could not figure it out at all. Would anyone please help me? Thanks

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
INCLUDE macros.inc
.data

Array1 DWord 2,4,6,8,10
Array2 DWord 5 Dup(0)

.code
main PROC

mov edx, OFFSET Array1
mov esi, OFFSET Array2
mov ecx, LENGTHOF Array1
mov eax, 0

Call Dumpregs

Call Dumpregs
L1:
mWrite "Hello"
Call CRLF

Loop L1


Call Dumpregs

L2:

mov eax, [edx]

mov [esi], eax
add esi, 4
add edx, 4

Loop L2


exit

main ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 1):

Your *L2* loop cannot produce the desired result since the preceding code wiped ECX clean (You used `loop L1`). To copy the array you need to re-initialize ECX. Also it's best to setup the pointers EDX and ESI close to this *L2* loop because perhaps there is a risk of them being modified by all those preceding (macro)calls!

```
mov  edx, OFFSET Array1
mov  esi, OFFSET Array2
mov  ecx,5
L2:
mov  eax,[edx]
mov  [esi],eax
add  esi, 4
add  edx, 4
loop L2
```